# C# set text box cursor position works if a breakpoint is hit, not otherwise

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Environment:  VS 2012 on Win7 Pro box.

I have a control I derived from TextBox.  The control's text is initialized to "00".  I want to make sure that the cursor is positioned at the end of the text string, if it exists, whenever the control becomes active.

I have three of these controls contained in a user control.  I can only get the cursor positioning to work the way I want it if all of the following are true:

1. I have overridden OnEnter() in my textbox-derived control.
2. I have overridden OnGotFocus() in my textbox-derived control.
3. I am running my test form in the debugger.
4. I have a breakpoint set at the start of OnEnter().

Here are my overrides:

```
    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnEnter(e);
        if (Text.Length > 0)
        {
            SelectionStart = Text.Length;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
        if (Text.Length > 0)
        {
            SelectionStart = Text.Length;
        }
    }
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote does work when you switch to the textbox using the tab key (I just tested it to confirm).
It doesn't work when you click the textbox with the mouse. The reason for that is probably due to the fact that dot net sets the caret to the mouse cursor location, and it does that after the `GotFocus` event gets fired (and the `GotFocus` event is fired after the `Enter` event is fired, according to this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus(v=vs.110).aspx).

I don't have an elegant solution to this, but until somebody comes up with something better, you can add a small delay (which is what happens when you break with the debugger) which seems to work fine for me:

```
    protected override async void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
        await Task.Delay(10);
        if (Text.Length > 0)
        {
            SelectionStart = Text.Length;
        }
    }
```